# Can I make refference to ArrayBuffer at offset?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I convert data from JavaScript variables to `ArrayBuffer` and back. Think of this function:

```
function numberToArrayBuffer(number) {
    return new Float64Array([number]).buffer;
}
```

And other way around:

```
function numberFromArrayBuffer(buffer) { 
    // Assuming implicitly, that the buffer is long enough
    return new Float64Array(buffer, 0, 1)[0];
}
```

That works, but imagine you stuff more of these numbers in Blob:

```
var numbers = new Blob([numberToArrayBuffer(66), numberToArrayBuffer(666), numberToArrayBuffer(NaN)], {type:"binary/Float64Array"});
```

If you read that using file reader, you can get `ArrayBuffer` again:

```
var fl = new FileReader();
fl.onload = function() {
  console.log(Float64Array(this.result));  
}
fl.readAsArrayBuffer(numbers);
```

And you get something like this:

```
 Float64Array { 0=66,  1=666,  2=NaN}
```

But of course, there could be sequences od different types, like 2 `unrestricted double`s and 4 `uint32_t`. So I would like do something like this (but there is no `.offset` metod):

```
var num1 = numberFromArrayBuffer(buffer);
// Shift by 8 bytes - if only `offset(8)` was defined
var num2 = byteFromArrayBuffer(buffer.offset(8));
```

Of course, I can make a *"overloaded function"*:

```
function numberToArrayBuffer(number, offset) {
    return new Float64Array([number], offset||0).buffer;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var num2 = byteFromArrayBuffer(buffer, 8);
```

But I'd prefer an equivalent of this C++ code:

```
void main()
{
    uint8_t* bytes = loadBytesFromSomewhere();
    // Read 4 bytes and make an int
    uint32_t integer = intFromBytes(bytes);
    // Read 2 bytes and make a short
    uint16_t short_integer = shortFromBytes(bytes+4);
    delete bytes;
}
```

I want this because it's really annoying to put offset aspect to decoding algorithms. At the same time, I really want to be consistent and use `ArrayBuffer`, which can be turned to any data type array at will.

Is there a trick? I tried this:

```js
//Make 20 bytes
var buffer = new Uint8Array(20);
console.log("Original buffer: ",buffer.byteLength);
//Try to offset the buffer                off cnt
var shiftedArray = new Uint8Array(buffer, 10, 10);
var shiftedBuffer = shiftedArray.buffer;
console.log("Shifted buffer? Length:",shiftedBuffer.byteLength);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Not only that it doesn't work, but also exhibits possible dangerous and confusing behavior of typed arrays created with an offset - their length can be significantly smaller than their `ArrayBuffer` length.

Comment: In your JS code you seem to want to read multiple values whereas in the C++ code you're reinterpretting the same value. I don't understand your question.

Comment: No, I'm not reinterpreting the same value. If you use `+` operation on pointer you shift it by that amount of entries of the datatype it represents. So `bytes+4` points somewhere else than `bytes`. And I would like to do the same to `ArrayBuffer` - make it point few bytes forward so that decoding functions do not have to offset it using second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may or may not exactly meet your needs, I believe it's the equivalent of what you desired in c++ (minus the delete bytes). Though, this is an old post and you may have your answer already!

As you already know, `ArrayBuffers` in javascript can be accessed through a handful of different viewpoints/objects, called TypedArrays. These are objects such as Float64Array, Uint32Array, etc. There is a TypedArray object that allows you to grab data back dynamically to whatever type you would like at target byte offsets called a `DataView`.

So to achieve the desired functionality you could do something like the following:

```
var buffer = loadByteBufferFromSomewhere();

//DataView would be the same way
var dv = new DataView(buffer);
//uint32 at index 0;
dv.getUint32(0);
//uint16 starting at byte 4
dv.getUint16(4);

//get a target byte at given indexes
dv.getUint8(0);
dv.getUint8(1);
```

DataView is a wrapper around the ArrayBuffer like Float64Array, Uint32Array, etc. You can also set target types at given indexes as well. I've found [JavaScripture's references really helpful TypedArrays](http://www.javascripture.com/DataView)